# Fortran type mismatch error

Tags: types, compiler-construction, fortran, real-datatype

In this fortran program I've been given and told to debug, I'm getting the error:

"type mismatch in argument 'p1' at (1); passed REAL(4) to TYPE(point)"

and I can't seem to figure out where the error is occuring.
I've tried defining different variables to pass to each function instead of p1 and p2 with the same error. Any ideas?

```
MODULE PointType

TYPE POINT
REAL:: x
REAL:: y
END TYPE

CONTAINS

FUNCTION arePointsEqual(p1, p2)
REAL:: arePointsEqual
TYPE(POINT), INTENT(IN):: p1
TYPE(POINT), INTENT(IN):: p2
LOGICAL :: isEqual
IF ( p1%x == p2%x .AND. p1%y == p2%y) THEN
isEqual = .TRUE.
ELSE
isEqual = .FALSE.
END IF
END FUNCTION

 FUNCTION arePointsNotEqual(p1,p2)
 REAL:: arePointsNotEqual
 TYPE(POINT), INTENT(IN):: p1
 TYPE(POINT), INTENT(IN):: p2
 LOGICAL :: isNotEqual

 IF ( p1%x == p2%x .AND. p1%y == p2%y) THEN
 isNotEqual = .FALSE.
 ELSE
 isNotEqual = .TRUE.
 END IF
 END FUNCTION

 FUNCTION distance(p1, p2)
 REAL:: distance
 TYPE(POINT), INTENT(IN):: p1
 TYPE(POINT), INTENT(IN):: p2
 distance = SQRT((p2%x - p1%x)**2 + (p2%y - p1%y)**2)
 END FUNCTION

 END MODULE

 !MAIN PROGRAM BELOW THIS LINE

 PROGRAM Project3

 USE PointType

 PRINT *, arePointsEqual(p1, p2)

 PRINT *, arePointsNotEqual(p1, p2)

 PRINT *, distance(p1, p2)

 END PROGRAM Project3
```

Comment: You have neither declared `p1` and `p2`, nor given them meaningful values. Without `IMPLICIT NONE` the compiler implicitly makes `p1` and `p2` of type `REAL`, hence the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: try "implicit none".  Always a good idea.

Comment: Well, you should give it an explicit type, i.e., declare its type.