# Fortran Error: Type mismatch in argument ‘n’ at (1); passed REAL(4) to INTEGER(4)

Tags: compiler-errors, fortran

I am learning Fortran, specifically modules. I wrote this simple code that should calculate the derivative of the sine function:

```
module constants
    real, parameter::x=3.14
    real, parameter::h=0.0001
end module constants

module derivata1

contains
    real function der1(n)
        use constants
        real::der
        der=(sin(x+h)-sin(x))/h
    end function der1
end module derivata1
program derivate
    use constants
    use derivata1
    implicit none
    real der1

    print *, der1(x)
end program derivate
```

I get the following error in gfortran.

```
der2.f90:40.10:

 real der1
          1
der2.f90:38.5:

 use derivata1
     2
Error: Symbol 'der1' at (1) conflicts with symbol from module 'derivata1', use-associated at (2)
der2.f90:44:15:

  print *, der1(x)
               1
Error: Type mismatch in argument ‘n’ at (1); passed REAL(4) to INTEGER(4)
```

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39667681/2853667) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13486909/2853667) posts, but with no result.

Where is my error?

Comment: Please try to post complete error messages in your questions. Tell us which compiler you are using. This looks like gfortran, gfortran normally prints more useful information than just the part you chose to show us. The best thing is to show the complete output including the command you executed.

Comment: @VladimirF Added the full message

Answer (score 1):

You should use `IMPLICIT NONE` in all your compilation units.

Inside the module you have no `IMPLICIT NONE` so the argument `n` is implicitly integer because it is not declared to be otherwise.

Also, you should not do any

```
real der1
```

in the program where you want to use function `der1` from a module, because that makes the function to be declared external. The compiler then thinks you are calling some other function `der1` which is somewhere else, but not in that module.

Comment: However, there is so much more wrong with the program that correcting simply these will not suffice in producing something useable.

Comment: Indeed the function is completely wrong. I checked just those two errors that concerned use of modules.

Comment: @VladimirF please tell me what else is wrong, I will never learn otherwise.

Comment: @mattiav27 You don't use the function argument `n` in the function in any way, you reference the global parameter `x`. You define some useless variable `der` in the function and assign the computation result into this variable instead of assigning to the function name `der1`. Why the global parameter `x=3.14` should exist is unclear to me, in my opinion it is useless.